# How to Get posts by Taxonomy if Checkbox is Checked in Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom taxonomy registered for custom post type and pages with same value
how can get posts when the checkbox is checked by taxonomy in Pges .

This To Get Terms in variable

```
    $category = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => false,

    ]);
$category = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => false,

    ]);
    $property_area = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => 'property_area',
        'hide_empty' => false,

    ]);
    $property_type = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => 'property_type',
        'hide_empty' => false,

    ]);
```

WordPress  query

```
$rent_properties = array(
    'post_type' => 'properties',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation'=>'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy'=>'category',
            'field' => 'field_id',
            'terms' => $category,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'=>'property_area',
            'field'  => 'fild_id',
            'terms' =>$property_area,

        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'=>'property_type',
            'field'  => 'slug',
            'terms' => $property_type

        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Create a template and assign this template to the all desired pages that have those taxonomies

2-In this template code, detect the selected taxonomy(that you have been chosen from admin panel page editor)

3-In the template code, get all posts that have those taxonomy

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'jazz'
        )
    )
);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

Reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts